# .htaccess on Dreamhost shared hosting

Tags: .htaccess, shared-hosting, dreamhost

I have mod_rewrite working perfectly on my local machine, but I'm getting a redirect loop on my shared server at Dreamhost.

I think I'm missing something really obvious.  Any ideas why this would not work on a shared server?

I'm using Linux/Apache/PHP 5.2 with FastCGI

```
# Turn on URL rewriting 
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteBase /

# Protect application files from being viewed 
RewriteRule ^(application) - [F,L] 

# Allow any other files or directories that exist to be displayed directly 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/ 
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having the same issue: turning off FastCGI solved the problem.